# SQL constraint for between multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Here is my table

```
Events
Start : Datetime
End : Datetime
```

I'm trying to make sure that a new Event does not overlap any previously entered events.  I'll admit my SQL knowledge is novice at best.  The following is a select statement that gets me close but I can't figure out how to turn it into a constraint (would I use check?)

```
SELECT e.*
FROM Events
WHERE Start BETWEEN e.START and e.END
OR End BETWEEN new.START and new.END
OR (Start < e.Start and End > e.End)
```

I'd imagine if something like that returned anything at all there's overlap.

Edit: updated "sql" statement to cover for a logical failure on my part.  It's most likely still poorly formed.  I really appreciate all of the help!

Comment: For what database?  CHECK constraints exist on MySQL, but aren't enforced

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server.  Version 9.00.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would actually have to go into code or a trigger. A constraint operates at the row level only

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_Events_INSERT On EventsFOR INSERT
AS
IF EXISTS (SELECT *
    FROM Events E
        JOIN
        INSERTED INS
         ON
           (E.Start Between INS.START and INS.END)
          OR
           (E.End Between INS.START and INS.END)
          OR
           (E.Start < INS.START and E.End > INS.END)

     WHERE
        E.Key <> INS.Key --already inserted at this point

BEGIN
   ROLLBACK TRAN
   --etc
END
GO
```

Answer (score 3):

The SQL you provided isn't syntactically correct - use:

```
SELECT e.*
  FROM EVENTS e
 WHERE start BETWEEN e.START and e.END
    OR end BETWEEN e.START and e.END
    OR (start < e.START AND end > e.END)
```

`BETWEEN` is inclusive, and supported consistently on all databases.

Comment: This doesn't cover the case of an event that starts prior to an existing event and ends after that event has completed.

Comment: Cheeky monkey!  OK, +1 it is then.  Admittedly, the OP didn't mention that this constitutes an overlap, but we know it does.  :)

Comment: I think we both fixed that one at about the same time.  Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

This'll probably depend on the DBMS you're using, but such a constraint would usually need to be implemented using a *trigger* which performs a query to determine whether the insert/update is valid and rolls back the transaction if not.  CHECK constraints typically only allow to you refer to columns in the 'current row'.

```
SELECT *
FROM Events E
WHERE E.Start <= NEWEND
AND E.End >= NEWSTART
```

...will get you the events that are overlapped with (change <= and >= with < and > if you're not interested in 'touching' events).

Comment: What no upvotes, not even half a vote for my innovative 'overlaps' checking?  Tsk!

Comment: +1: For catching the date overlap.  I voted for GBN's answer for sake of all out trigger code.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is compare the table to itself in a join. Below is an example on how to do that. I commented out some lines. Uncomment them to see it progress to deal with different cases.

*edit:* If you need this as a constraint on the table itself you should go with a trigger.

*edit2:* For SQL 2005 replace the insert syntax with separate insert statements.

Good luck,

GJ

```
declare @event table (
    Id int,
    Start DateTime,
    Stop DateTime
)

insert  @event (Id, Start, Stop)
values  (1, '2010-08-01', '2010-08-02')
    ,(2, '2010-08-04', '2010-08-06')
    ,(3, '2010-08-05', '2010-08-08')    -- start fals within event 2
    --,(4, '2010-01-01', '2010-12-31')  -- overlaps with all of them
    --,(5, '2010-08-01', '2010-08-02')      -- equal to event 1

select  *
from    @event e1
        inner join @event e2 
            on  e1.Id != e2.Id          -- do not compare to itself
            and e2.Start >= e1.Start    -- events that have a start date
            and e2.Start <= e1.Stop
```